# Why won't my slide print

Tags: vba, printing, powerpoint

I created my first VBA quiz for my computer class and need the results to print. I pasted the PrintablePage and PrintResults after comparing to several models I found online.  Please tell where I'm going wrong.  The results page comes right up but the print button will not work.

```
Sub PrintablePage()
Dim printableSlide As Slide
Dim printbutton As Shape
Dim donebutton As Shape

Set printableSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=8, Layout:=ppLayoutText)
printableSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test results for " & Username
printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "You got " & numberRight & " out of " & _
numberRight + numberWrong & "." & Chr$(13) & "Please press print."

Set donebutton = ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, 0, 0, 150, 50)
donebutton.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Close Program"
donebutton.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionRunMacro
donebutton.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = "done"

Set printbutton = ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(2).AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, 400, 400, 100, 100)
printbutton.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Print"
printbutton.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionRunMacro
printbutton.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = "PrintResults"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
ActivePresentation.Saved = True
End Sub

Sub PrintResults()
donebutton.Visible = False
printbutton.Visible = False
ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.OutputType = ppPrintOutputSlides
ActivePresentation.PrintOut From:=8, To:=8
donebutton.Visible = True
printbutton.Visible = True
End Sub

Sub done()
MsgBox "The program will shut down now"
ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Delete
ActivePresentation.Saved = msoCTrue
ActivePresentation.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Any help would so be appreciated.

Comment: I don't even know where that 2 came from, probably because I've tried every one I can find.  Anyway, I don

Comment: @portlandrunner  Thank you for helping. I don't even know where that 2 came from, probably because I've tried every one I can find.  Anyway, I don't have a 2 in mine and it still won't print. Printable page with results, no problem.  Delete results page when it shuts down, no problem. But print...nothing works. Every sample I compare to is the same, except the slide index of course.  This is so frustrating and yet exciting, it's like a good mystery to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add a shape to an existing index.  PowerPoint doesn't allow this.

Change:

```
Set printbutton = ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(2).AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, 400, 400, 100, 100)
```

To:

```
Set printbutton = ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, 400, 400, 100, 100)
```

---

If you use intellisense while typing you'll notice that if you add an index to `Shapes(2)` then `AddShape` is not an option but if you only use `Shapes.` then `AddShape` is a valid method.